# How do i pass arraycollection to Advancedatagrid using HierarchicalData?

Tags: php, apache-flex, datagrid, flash

Problem with passing arraycollection to Advance datagrid.   My  Arraycollection structure like `

```
private var groupList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
 {Country:'India', children:[

     {Country:'Series1', children:[
                               {Matches:'India Test series 1',isEnable:false,id:1,isSelected:true},
                               {Matches:'India Test series 2',isEnable:false,id:2,isSelected:true},
                               {Matches:'India Test series 3',isEnable:false,id:3,isSelected:true}]},
              {Country:'Series2', children:[
                               {Matches:'Australia Test series 1',isEnable:false,id:25,isSelected:true},
                               {Matches:'Australia Test series 2',isEnable:false,id:26,isSelected:true},
                               {Matches:'Australia Test series 3',isEnable:false,id:27,isSelected:true}]}

    ]},
{Country:'Austrila', children:[

    {Country:'Series1', children:[
                               {Matches:'Australia Test series 1',isEnable:false,id:46,isSelected:true},
                               {Matches:'Australia Test series 2',isEnable:false,id:47,isSelected:true},
                               {Matches:'Australia Test series 3',isEnable:false,id:48,isSelected:true}]},
{Country:'Series2', children:[
                               {Matches:'Australia Test series 1',isEnable:false,id:49,isSelected:true},
                               {Matches:'Australia Test series 2',isEnable:false,id:50,isSelected:true},
                               {Matches:'Australia Test series 3',isEnable:false,id:51,isSelected:true}]},
{Country:'Series3', children:[
                               {Matches:'Australia Test series 1',isEnable:false,id:52,isSelected:true},
                               {Matches:'Australia Test series 2',isEnable:false,id:53,isSelected:true},
                               {Matches:'Australia Test series 3',isEnable:false,id:54,isSelected:true}]}

]}
```

passing AD in `dataProvider="{new HierarchicalData(groupList)}"` It's working fine. it's show two menu of tree and childrens based on country  .But i tried dynamic xml convert to Arraycollection by below code

```
private function convertXmlToArrayCollection( file:String ):ArrayCollection
   {
    var xml:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument( file );



    //var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder();


   var decoder1:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder(true);


    var data1:Object = decoder1.decodeXML( xml );

    var array1:Array = ArrayUtil.toArray(data1);

    return new ArrayCollection( array1 );
   }
```

my xml structure is

```
 <Country Country="India ">
    <Country Country="Series ">
      <Matches Matches="BIndependiente-Colon" id="701536" isEnable="false" isSelected="true" startDate="2009-10-29 01:30:00" EndDate="2009-10-29 01:30:00"/>
      <Matches Matches="Boca Juniors-Chacarita Juniors" id="701633" isEnable="false" isSelected="true" startDate="2009-10-29 19:00:00" EndDate=""/>
    </Country>
  </Country>

    <Country Country="Australia">
    <Country Country="series">
      <Matches Matches="BIndependiente-Colon" id="701536" isEnable="false" isSelected="true" startDate="2009-10-29 01:30:00" EndDate="2009-10-29 01:30:00"/>
      <Matches Matches="Boca Juniors-Chacarita Juniors" id="701633" isEnable="false" isSelected="true" startDate="2009-10-29 19:00:00" EndDate=""/>
    </Country>
  </Country>
```

So if i tried to convert this format of xml code to arryacollection  , it  converted the array collection but when will i pass to Advance data grid it not show any result . What did i wrong ?

```
groupList1= convertXmlToArrayCollection(string1);
Alert.show(groupList1[0].Country[0].Matches[0].id.toString());// output is =701536
```

Where did i mistake it ? Plz kindly any one refer me  , What will i changed ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make groupList1 [Bindable]? Also when you set it to the datagrids dataprovider, was it through binding or just simple assignment?

Also have you tried calling `'invalidateDisplayList()'` on the datagrid.

Also another option you could try is setting the xml directly as the dataprovider (don't convert to an ArrayCollection).

hope that helps